# Why does constructor work with wrong parameters?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a constructor

```
T(someClass<double> o);
```

The class `someClass` is initialized by `double* x`. That is

```
someClass<double>(double * X);
```

Why does the following work?

```
double * X=new X[10];
T obj(X);
```

Why does this work, even though that there is no constructor for `T`, that takes `double *` as an argument (it should get an instance of `someClass`)? Does the compiler implicitly initialize someClass, from `double*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`someClass<double>(double * X);` could be regarded as [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor), which could convert `double*` to `someClass<double>` implicitly.

For `T obj(X);`, the compiler will check all the possible constructors of `T` to construct `obj`; and might find a possible way that implicitly converts `X` to `someClass<double>` and then use it as the argument for `T(someClass<double> o)`.

You can prohibit unintended implicit conversion by making the constructor `explicit`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was driving me crazy, and I couldn't find anything on google (as I didnt know the term converting constructor)... When the timer allows, I will accept this answer.

Comment: If you don't want your constructor to be used for implicit conversions, declare it with `explicit`.